# Does MySQL have max(a,b) function?

Tags: mysql, sql

Does MySQL have `max(a,b)` function? I mean a simple math function from two numbers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You mean [**GREATEST( )**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

```
GREATEST(A, b)
```